# How to create a view from existing table records, but also adding new records that do not exist

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table, insert-into, create-view

I am trying to create a view from an existing views data, but also if there are certain lines that do not exist per part/date combo, then have those lines be created.  I have the below query that is showing what I currently have for the particular `s_date/part_no` combos:

```
SELECT
    s_date,
    part_no,
    issue_group,
    s_level,
    qty_filled
FROM
    current_view
WHERE
    part_no = 'xxxxx'
    AND s_date IN (
        '201802',
        '201803'
    )
ORDER BY
    s_date,
    part_no,
    issue_group,
    DECODE(s_level, '80', 1, '100', 2, 'Late', 3)
```

Which produces the below:

[image]

I know how to create a view with that data, that's the easy part. But what I'm needing is a line for each `issue_group and s_level` combo, and if it's a created line, to put 0 as the `qty_filled`.

Every `part_no / s_date` combo should have 6 rows that go with it

```
 - issue_group = '1' / s_level = '80'
 - issue_group = '1' / s_level = '100'
 - issue_group = '1' / s_level = 'Late'
 - issue_group = '2/3 ' / s_level = '80'
 - issue_group = '2/3 ' / s_level = '100'
 - issue_group = '2/3 ' / s_level = 'Late'
```

So if one of the above combinations already exists for the current `s_date/part_no`, then it obviously takes the `qty_filled` info from the current view. If not, a new line is created, and `qty_filled = 0`. So I'm trying to get it to look like this:

[image]

I've only shown 1 part, with a couple dates, just to get the point across. There are 10k+ parts within the table and there will never be more than 1 part/date combo for each of the 6 issue_group/s_level combos.

Comment: Extract unique issue_group and s_level combinations and `LEFT JOIN` it to your query.

Comment: @PM77-1 but I currently only have 1 table, so how does that work? Or do I first have to create that table/view with every issue_group and s_level combo and then do the join?

Comment: Write a query to produce unique combinations and use it's result for `JOIN`.

Comment: Hello @PM77-1, would you please tag your question with the RDBMS that you are using : oracle, mysql, sql-server...?

Comment: @GMB I'm sorry I thought I added the RDBMS within my tags ... but it is Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to generate the rows using `CROSS JOIN` and then bring in the extra information with a `LEFT JOIN`.  In Oracle syntax, this looks like:

```
WITH v as (
      SELECT v.*
      FROM current_view v
      WHERE part_no = 'xxxxx' AND
            s_date IN ('201802', '201803')
    )
SELECT d.s_date, ig.part_no, ig.issue_group, l.s_level,
       COALESCE(v.qty_filled, 0) as qty_filled
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT s_date FROM v) d CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT part_no, ISSUE_GROUP FROM v) ig CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT '80' as s_level FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT '100' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 'LATE' FROM DUAL
     ) l LEFT JOIN
     v
     ON v.s_date = d.s_date AND v.part_no = ig.part_no AND
        v.issue_group = ig.issue_group AND v.s_level = l.s_level
ORDER BY s_date, part_no, issue_group,
         (CASE s_level WHEN  '80' THEN 1 WHEN '100' THEN 2 WHEN 'Late' THEN 3 END)
```

Comment: Thank you!! I removed the where clause in the initial with statement and it still worked for all parts/dates within the view. The cross join and complexity of this is slightly over my head, so now I've got some more learning to do. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to generate a cartesian product of all expected rows using a cartesian product between the (fixed) list of values, and then `LEFT JOIN` it with `current_view`.

The following query guarantees that you will get a record for each given `s_date/part_no/issue_group/s_level` tuple. If no record matches in `current_view`, the query will display a `0` quantity.

```
SELECT
    sd.s_date,
    pn.part_no,
    ig.issue_group,
    sl.s_level,
    COALESCE(cv.qty_filled, 0) qty_filled
FROM
    (SELECT '201802' AS s_date UNION SELECT '201803') AS sd
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'xxxxx' AS part_no) AS pn
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT '1' AS issue_group UNION SELECT '2') AS ig
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT '80' AS s_level UNION SELECT '100' UNION SELECT 'Late') AS sl
    LEFT JOIN current_view cv 
        ON  cv.s_date      = sd.s_date
        AND cv.part_no     = pn.part_no
        AND cv.issue_group = ig.issue_group
        AND cv.s_level     = ig.s_level
ORDER BY
    sd.s_date,
    pn.part_no,
    ig.issue_group,
    DECODE(sl.s_level, '80', 1, '100', 2, 'Late', 3)
```

NB : you did not tag your RDBMS. This should work on most of them, excepted Oracle, where you need to add `FROM DUAL` to each select in the queries that list the allowed values, like :

```
(SELECT '201802' AS s_date FROM DUAL UNION SELECT '201803' FROM DUAL) AS sd
```